# Quiero crear una macro de excel que inserte cierto numero de filas debajo de una celda seleccionada

Tags: excel, macros

he intentado hacerlo con el siguiente codigo pero solo puedo insertar una fila, necesito insertar varias filas

```
codigo
Sub InsertarFilas()

Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te pongo una función que te inserta el número de filas que deseas, puedes adaptarla a tus necesidades

Para usar ésta función simplemente agregas un botón a tu hoja excel y lo enlazas a la función insertando un nuevo módulo

```
Sub FuncionInsertarFilas()

    Dim numeroFilas As Long
 
    'Pregunta por medio de InputBox al usuario por el número de filas a insertar
    'El numero de filas lo almacena en la variable numeroFilas
    numeroFilas = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Filas a insertar:", Type:=1)
 
    'Verificamos que el número de filas a insertar sea mayor a cero
    If numeroFilas > 0 Then
        'Utilizamos el método .insert para añadir las filas a continuación de la fila activa, o sea, por debajo de la calde seleccionada
        Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row + numeroFilas - 1).Insert
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Inserta3Filas()

    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveCell.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

  
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
    
   Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).